# What other sacred/legendary places exist that are like Mount Myoboku, Ryuuchi Cave, and Shikkotsu Forest?

Tags: naruto

The locations that have been mentioned where one can learn sage mode are:

1. [Mount Myoboku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku)
2. [Ryuuchi Cave](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ry%C5%ABchi_Cave)
3. [Shikkotsu Forest](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shikkotsu_Forest)

I am interested to know if any other places exist that are on-par with these places, such as a place where a legendary event has occurred. (Example: A place of hawk, summoned by Sasuke while fighting against Danzo).

Answer (score 4):

We *know* that there are other types of creatures, Gai summoned a turtle, Temrai summoned a weasel, and I'm not even beginning to talk about Pain's Chikshodo.

However, as for the "homes" of said summoned creatures, only 3 have been confirmed. The 3 you listed.

1. [Mount Myoboku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_My%C5%8Dboku)
2. [Ryūchi Cave](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ry%C5%ABchi_Cave)
3. [Shikkotsu Forest](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shikkotsu_Forest)

Comment: pain's chikshodo summons were dead animals infused with pain's chakra receivers. they are summoned from dead world( or watever it is) using rinnegan.

Comment: @Sreepati: Unlikely. If the summoned animals are anything like the bodies from the Rikudo no Jutsu, then it's likely that they're summoned from some sort of safe-house, a lab or something similar. The animals are dead bodies imbued with Yin rods.

Comment: in one canon episode they were trying to make the ultimate kuchiyose animal in a lab in an island. maybe from some similar island or something , i guess.

Comment: @Sreepati: I don't remember such an episode, do you remember which it was?

Comment: yeah there was one filler episode. in that they created an animal looking like a baby or something in an island. maybe during the naruto's journey to killer bee island.